# What rendering technology does 2048 use?

Tags: html, html5-canvas, webgl

I am currently looking through the 2048 source code and having trouble determining what rendering technology the game uses. Does anyone know what or how to figure out how 2048 renders tiles? I'm guessing the html5 canvas 2d context, or WebGL.

Comment: Show us the source code link.

Comment: It uses two 1024 rendering engines.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about [this version of 2048](https://github.com/gabrielecirulli/2048), the answer is just HTML and CSS (and JavaScript, of course). No canvas, no WebGL. You can see most of the DOM manipulation logic in [`js/html_actuator.js`](https://github.com/gabrielecirulli/2048/blob/master/js/html_actuator.js) and the SCSS (and compiled CSS) for the animations in [`style`](https://github.com/gabrielecirulli/2048/tree/master/style).